# Update photoURL Firebase v9 web, react Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm following a Udemy firebase Udemy tutorial for creating a firebase web application using javascript and react. The course material is a bit our of date. I want to know how to change a user's photoURL - they log up with email and password, and I have a seperate hook to handle the sign up information.

Below is the code the Udemy course gives to update a user's photoURL - does anyone know how I would write this in Firebase v9? Thank you!

```
// upload user thumbnail
      const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`
      const img = await projectStorage.ref(uploadPath).put(thumbnail)
      const imgUrl = await img.ref.getDownloadURL()

      // add display AND PHOTO_URL name to user
      await res.user.updateProfile({ displayName, photoURL: imgUrl })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting from pre-v9 to v9 is usually quite simple, especially if you follow the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) or compare the v8 and v9 samples in the documentation on [uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).

In your code, this v8 code:

```
const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`
const img = await projectStorage.ref(uploadPath).put(thumbnail)
const imgUrl = await img.ref.getDownloadURL()

// add display AND PHOTO_URL name to user
await res.user.updateProfile({ displayName, photoURL: imgUrl })
```

Becomes this in v9 and above:

```
const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`
const img = await uploadBytes(ref(projectStorage, uploadPath, thumbnail))
const imgUrl = await getDownloadUrl(img.ref)

// add display AND PHOTO_URL name to user
await updateProfile(res.user, { displayName, photoURL: imgUrl })
```

If you watch carefully, you'll see that most of the change is just in moving the namespaced `object.operation()` method calls into a modular/functional `operation(object)` form. Aside from that, the biggest difference here is that `put` is now called `uploadBytes`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked. Although when I try to display the photo by setting an img src to user.photoURL it displays a broken img and the alt text. When I inspect the code, the img src has the correct URL - do you know why the image isn't displaying?

Comment: I see you already posted a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71076128/broken-image-displaying-when-using-firebase-photourl) for this problem, so hope somebody can help you there.